# SSRS: How to restore a deleted title in a chart

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I made some charts and deleted the titles.  I decided that was the wrong thing to do and want to put them back.  Is there any way to do this that doesn't involve redoing the chart?

Comment: I take it it's too late for ctrl-Z? :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply right-click the chart and choose "Add New Title"

[image: context menu screenshot]

Note: Depending on where you right-click on the chart, the "Add New Title" item might be in a sub menu.

[image]

Comment: For cryin' out loud, here I am trying to look at chart areas and the answer is so simple!  You'd think I would have seen that menu option at some point.  Thanks for the info!